# Truncate/trim/reformat zip codes

Tags: string, r, zipcode

I have a data frame with a column of zip codes that are in different formats: 12345, 12345-, 12345 - 6789, 12345-6789, and 123456789.  I need just the first 5 digits- 12345.  How can I reformat/trim/truncate so that they are are in the same format?  The zip codes are factors.

```
df<- data.frame(list(id = c(1:5), zip = c("12345", "12345-", "12345 - 6789", "12345-6789", "123456789")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that there is nothing before these five numbers you want you can use `stri_sub` function from `stringi` package like this:

```
stri_sub("123456789",1,5)
## [1] "12345"
```

To extract only numbers from string vector use another function from this package:

```
stri_extract_all_charclass("aa  bb12345lfda124\t43","Nd")
## [[1]]
## [1] "12345" "124"   "43"
```

This function extracts all substrings that matches class. In this case "Nd" - numeric digital, but there is more class, look at doc :)

Comment: Thanks - that works.  Is there anyway to ensure there's nothing before the first five digits?

Comment: Yes, there is :) Look at my post now! :)

Answer (score 2):

No need for an add on package, `strtrim` is perfect for this:

```
strtrim(df$zip, 5)
## [1] "12345" "12345" "12345" "12345" "12345"
```